# execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:

Tags: trigger

```
trigger DemoTrigger on Contact (after insert,after update)
  {

   Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
   for(Contact con : Trigger.new)
   {
    accIdList.add(con.accountid);
   }

 List<account> acList=[Select id, name,RollUp__c,(Select Id,value__c ,x__c,y__c  From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList];
        for(Account acc : acList) {
      for(Contact con : acc.contacts) {
     if((con.value__c).equalsIgnoreCase('+'))
   {
            acc.RollUp__c    = con.x__c;
   }
  else if((con.value__c).equalsIgnoreCase('-'))

    {
        acc.RollUp__c    = con.y__c;
    }                                               
  }
  }
      update acList;
  }
```

What is wrong with this code.please help me.

Comment: Please provide line number , where you are receiving Null pointer exception ?

Comment: After a first read it feels like the only thing that could cause this error is that `con.value__c` is null.

Comment: On line no 13 I am getting exception

Comment: @Basti yeah your are right if((con.value__c).equalsIgnoreCase('+')) causing the exception add null check for con.value__c using String.isNotBlank() that should work.

Answer (score 3):

Do not ever use `equalsIgnoreCase`. `==` does the exact same thing and is immune to NullPointerException:

```
trigger DemoTrigger on Contact (after insert,after update) {
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
  }
  List<account> acList=[Select (Select Id,value__c ,x__c,y__c  From Contacts) From Account Where Id In :accountIds];
  for(Account acc : acList) {
    for(Contact con : acc.contacts) {
      if(con.value__c == '+') {
        acc.RollUp__c    = con.x__c;
      } else if(con.value__c == '-') {
        acc.RollUp__c    = con.y__c;
      }
    }
  }
  update acList;
}
```

---

You could have also used a simple aggregate query instead:

```
trigger DemoTrigger on Contact (after insert,after update) {
  Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Rollup__c=0));
  }
  accounts.remove(null); // Skip private contacts
  for(AggregateResult ar: 
    [SELECT AccountId AccountId, SUM(X__c) xVal, SUM(Y__c) yVal, Value__c val 
     FROM Contact 
     WHERE Id = :accounts.keySet() and Value__c IN ('+','-')
     GROUP BY AccountId, Value__c]) {
   if(ar.get('val') == '+') {
     accounts.get((Id)ar.get('AccountId')).Rollup__c += (Decimal)ar.get('xVal');
   } else {
     accounts.get((Id)ar.get('AccountId')).Rollup__c += (Decimal)ar.get('yVal');
   }
 }
  update accounts.values();
}
```

Comment: I never realized == was case-insensitive for String comparisons.

Comment: @DavidCheng yep. equalsIgnoreCase is more for compatibility with Java rather than a useful language feature. I never use it myself.